Approximate a linear combination by one of fewer vectors
Given a $d\times n$ real matrix $M$ and a “weights” vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\sum w_i =1$ and $0\leq w_i\leq 1$ for all $i$, I'd like to find, for some fixed $m<n$, some $d\times m$ matrix $\widetilde M$ consisting of only $m$ columns of $M$ and a vector $\widetilde w\in \mathbb{R}^m$ (not necessarily of weights but perhaps subject to some of the constraints below) such that some vector norm $\|Mw-\widetilde{M}\widetilde{w}\|$ is minimized.
My idea is to get some linear combination of a small number of columns of $M$ such that they approximate the original linear combination of all $n$ columns given by $w$.
This sounds likely to be solved by some algorithm similar to PCA (principal component analysis) and dimensionality reduction (if not it). Nevertheless I'm not quite sure how to interpret the results of this proceses nor if they are in fact the way to proceed to get what I desire. Is this the right approach?
Possible constraints:

$\widetilde{w}$ is a weights vector
Sum of the entries of $\widetilde{w}$ equals 1
Sum of the positive entries of $\widetilde{w}$ is 1

